# ImgBurn in Wine

Tags: 14.04, wine, burning

I have installed imgburn through wine. i installed it fine and runs fine but when I try to burn a "iso" or "dvd" file it doesn't allow me...

when I select the source file, iso and dvd are not file type options.. therefore I can't even select them in the folder to burn.

anyone have any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use native Brasero or k3b to burn .iso and .img files instead of an emulated program that may not work 100%...